# Trouble with: Failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, firebase-realtime-database

[Attached screenshot for issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTGPX.png) Trying to display with table view. I keep getting the error:

> Failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource
>     class List:UITableViewController {

```
  var users = [user]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
       let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
   databaseRef.child("Users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
   snapshot in
   print(snapshot)


    let addNote = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["addNote"] as? String ?? ""
    let uid = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["uid"] as? String ?? ""
       self.users.append(user(addNote: addNote,uid: uid))
        self.tableView.reloadData()
          print(self.users)
 })

    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       print("Test\(users.count)")
       return users.count
        }


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    let nameLbl = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    nameLbl.text = self.users[indexPath.row].addNote
    return cell!

   }
```

Comment: Where are you creating `cell`? Your code as-is wouldn't even compile

Comment: I was trying to retrieve from firebase.. using swift3 Xcode 8... but when i run  this code which has custom cell it throws same error

Comment: You can't run the code you posted, it won't even compile. Copy and paste your actual `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: BTW - if you are new to iOS and Swift, you should be using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

Comment: Please check screenshot which i've attached in link provided

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Copy and paste the actual relevant code into your question. It makes it easier to read and it is much easier to reference when posting an answer.

Comment: It prints snapshot to console. it shows same data source error for table view

Comment: Try setting the delegate and datasource to self  in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

you will have to deque the tableviewcells

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:          IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
  return cell
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ok...as far as I understand you have your separate .xib file for your tableViewCell and not a prototype cell since, you are trying to register your nib with the tableview before using it. So, for that to happen correctly you need to ensure a few things:

1. You have specified an identifier for your tableView cell in the .xib file.
2. You use that identifier to register that cell, for eg.

   let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
           self.tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "abc")

Here,"abc" is the identifier.

3. Then, In cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate,

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("abc", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

I think you should use the above steps to register the nib and then deque it. It should work fine.

Comment: Look at the code in the question. The OP is already calling `register`.

Comment: In the code neither is any specific cell being registered nor dequed...and even if you don't want to deque (due to some reason), atleast you need to create an instance of the cell's class in order to perform the functions that are being performed in cellForRow.....

Comment: thanks for you reply maddy. Please check screenshot ive attached in link provided